# How do I format code in mobile Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, feature-request

Today I logged into Stack Overflow from a mobile.

I tried to give one answer, but my answer was not submitted as it was not properly formatted.

As far as I can see there is only one button for adding a picture above the body textarea for the answerbox in the mobile site.
Now the question is: How do I format code on the mobile site?

Is it that I have to request a desktop version from mobile?

Comment: What is this "mobile Stack Overflow" you speak of?

Comment: I mean mobile website.

Answer (score 6):

You format it manually, [with markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). The editor buttons in the full site are just there as a convenience, all they do is add the necessary markdown syntax when you click on them.

The [mobile apps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154797/do-stack-overflow-and-other-stack-exchange-sites-have-an-app-i-can-use) have a rich text editor but unfortunately the apps are no longer available.